# Move sent emails from Outlook to Yahoo server

Tags: yahoo-mail, outlook, thunderbird

I have a Yahoo email account on Outlook Express which uses POP3. I want to know how to upload all the emails I have in my sent folder to Yahoo server since now I want to manage my emails with IMAP.

I have found one solution but it has a problem. I added an IMAP account on Thunderbird and then I imported my sent folder from the Outlook account to Thunderbird. After that I move those mails to the sent folder of the IMAP account and I got what I wanted. All those emails are now in the Yahoo server. However, the emails headers were modified. This line was added at the beginning:

```
From <imap-client> Tue May 26 18:49:17 2009
```

but Yahoo web client is not showing the right date. It shows the email as sent with the date when I moved the emails in Thunderbird. For example, for that email instead of sort it using 26-05-2009, it uses 15-03-2013.

Does anyone know another way to do this without having the Yahoo web client problem?